# How can I understand "to which" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, usage

> Metaphor : a figure of speech in which a word or phrase is applied to an object or action to which it is not literally applicable

I don't know how to understand.
I tried to divide the sentence.
a figure of speech //in which a word or phrase is applied to an object or action //to which it is not literally applicable

1. what is the usage and meaning of "in which"?
2. what is the meaning of "is applied to"?
3. what is the usage and meaning of "to which"??

I tried to find the answer trolling the internet. There are tons of information so it's really difficult to find proper information.

After reading answers and replies, I tried to make sentence.

There is a figure of speech.
A word or phrase is applied to an object or action in the figure of speech. 
It is not literally applicable
to the object or action.

Is this right analysis? If so, what does "it" mean in the last sentence.

Comment: In *a figure of speech **in which** [something happens]*, the highlighted element refers back to *[a particular type of] **figure of speech*** - the implication being there are *other* "figures of speech" in which *something **else*** happens. ***Applied = used***, and ***to which*** refers back to *an object or action* (of a type that doesn't relate to the literal sense of the metaphor).

Comment: I'm assuming you do actually understand what ***metaphor*** means. If not, read several more definitions until you understand that, which will probably make it easier for you to understand the phrasing used in the particular definition you've cited above.

Comment: A small side note: while the original meaning of ***trolling*** is, in fact, "searching systematically", today it's much more common to use the word (especially when referring to the Internet) to mean "starting arguments by posting intentionally inflammatory comments". Which I hope you weren't doing :)

Comment: @MaciejStachowski you can substitute "trolling" for the phonetically similar "trawling"

Comment: @FumbleFingers OMG.... I can't understand your explanation.... ....

Comment: @TING CHOE: You've asked about three different parts of the dictionary definition, only two of which (1 & 3) are vaguely connected. Do you still not understand any of the three? Have you read any *other* definitions? Do you understand what the word "metaphor" means in English? Unless we know what you *do* know, it's not easy to guess what you *don't* know that might be worth explaining.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski You mean, Trolling has two meanings either , "searching systematically" and "starting arguments by posting intentionally inflammatory comments"? And the second meaning is commonly used? If so, can I use "trolling" here or not? I used as the first meaning.

Comment: Yes, your analysis is okay. In the last sentence, "it" refers to "a word or phrase". So this "word or phrase" that is applied to some object isn't literally applicable to it. We can't literally describe the world as a stage, but in the metaphor "all the world is a stage", we described it as one. A stage is the area in the theater where the performers perform, so how can the world be a stage? It can't; it literally makes no sense. If you think about it metaphorically, it's as if we're all actors, we all play different roles and the world is comparable to a huge stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a key.

And here is a lock to which the key belongs.

The key **belongs to** the lock. Hence, "**to** which the key belongs".

Here is a bowl. That is the cabinet **in which** the bowl belongs.

The bowl belongs **in** the cabinet.

Here is a vase, and that is the table **on which** the vase belongs.

The vase belongs **on** the table.

Here is a log cabin, and that is the forest **from which** the logs were harvested.

The logs were harvested **from** the forest.

Comment: I like your explanation. However, I have still difficulty to understand. Could you make sentences using my question sentence?

Comment: Your sample question is a very difficult one for learners. In my examples, I have given prepositional phrases ( on the *table*, in the *cabinet*, and from the *forest*) with physical objects, which makes it easier for a learner to understand the prepositions **on**, **in**, and **from**.  However, in your question, the noun is a metaphorical abstraction, "**figure** of speech". If you understand the word **figure** to be a kind of verbal **pattern**, then it becomes easier to see why we say "**in** the figure".  We can speak of the details and shapes which appear **in** a pattern.

Comment: The word **figure** is complex. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/figure   It has many *figurative* meanings (sorry for the pun) but at a basic literal level, it is a *shape* or *pattern*.

Comment: I analysed following your instructions.  Could you check my alanysis?

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is correct. Let's break down the original definition into separate sentences:

> Metaphor : a figure of speech in which a word or phrase is applied to an object or action to which it is not literally applicable.
>
> Metaphor is a figure of speech.
>
> In this figure of speech, a word or phrase is applied to an object or action.
>
> This word or phrase is not literally applicable to that object or action.

The opposite of *literal* is *figurative*. That is why metaphor is a **figure of speech**: it says something that is not literally true.

Here is an example:

> My apartment is a shambles.

*Shambles* means *slaughterhouse*, a place where animals are killed for meat. My apartment is not *literally* a slaughterhouse; I do not actually kill animals there. So the word *shambles* is **not literally applicable** to *my apartment*. So when I apply that word to this place, I am using it **metaphorically**.  What I'm actually saying is that my apartment is dirty and messy, in the same way that a slaughterhouse might be.

So I've used a *figure of speech* that takes a word, *shambles*, and applied it to an object, *my apartment*, to which the word is not literally applicable. And voilà: a metaphor. Makes sense?